# How do I get an inner div to overflow parent?

Tags: css, html, overflow

Please refer to this: http://jsfiddle.net/k8c7w/

I am trying to get the middle grey band (the one that says "HELLO WORLD!") to stretch across the entire screen. however, note that main has a very defined width.

Anyone know how I can fix this? The width of the main div needs to remain standard across all pages so I don't want to fiddle with that at all, and the other 2 bands (red bands) need to stay the same size as they are now.

Thanks StackOverflow!
Ringo

Comment: you can have `hello world` outside the main div and use absolute position to put it in the right place

Comment: Does the overflow on main have to be set to auto and do you know the height of the band divs?

Comment: I will then have to figure out the offset from left hand side of screen (which is dynamic). not doable I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a width for the middle div...

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/k8c7w/1/)

If you want to remove the scroll from the outer div, then remove the overflow property from `.main`. (as in the second set in the fiddle above)

Barring this method, if you don't want to specify a width for the middle div, you'd have to remove the containing div and specify width for the `.one` class as opposed to the `.main.` class.

Comment: well the issue is still that there is now a bunch of whitespace to the left of the grey bar. no idea how to flush the grey bar to the left!

Comment: You didn't mention you wanted it to protrude to the left as well. I really think the best construction would be to remove the container div's width and simply specify widths for the `.one` class. Seen Here: http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/k8c7w/3/ This method also allow the middle div to expand to the full window width.